# ASP.NET trailing slash issue in URL Rewrting

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, url-rewriting

I'm using [Intelligencia UrlRewriter](http://urlrewriter.net/) for URL Rewriting, the only issue I have is trailing slash.
I have this rule in `web.config`

```
<rewrite url="~/moviesarchive/(.+)" to="~/MoviesArchive.aspx?p=$1" />
```

it works when I use `http://localhost/site/moviesarchive/1`, I handled the situation when `p` parameter is null or empty, `http://localhost/site/MoviesArchive.aspx`, but when I remove trailing slash, `http://localhost/site/moviesarchive` or I use `http://localhost/site/moviesarchive/`, I get `HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found` error. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the Documentation at:
[http://urlrewriter.net/index.php/support/reference/actions/redirect](https://web.archive.org/web/20151104073357/http://urlrewriter.net/index.php/support/reference/actions/redirect)

Comment: With `<if>` how can I detect trailing slash does exist or not?

Comment: Use regex to perform your two conditions:

<if url="^http://localhost/site/(moviearchives|moviearchives/)$">
<redirect to="http://localhost/site/MoviesArchive.aspx" />
</if>

Comment: I was typing fast and overlooked a typo with my last comment.  I'm sure it's obvious but the urls should not have started with "localhost".  Use "~/" instead

Answer (score 0):

In your page load event add:

```
    Dim rawUrl As String = HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.Request.RawUrl
    If Not rawUrl.EndsWith("/") Then
        HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.Response.RedirectPermanent(String.Format("~{0}/", rawUrl))
    End If
```